Are Apple Hardware UUIDs guaranteed to be in standard UUID format
I'd like to put my Apple hardware UUIDs into a database, and I wonder if they are always in the standard UUID format. For example: b5e2cf01-8bb6-4fcd-ad88-0efb611195da 
Is there an Apple device in the last 10 years that has a non-standard hi-mom hardware UUID? What about an upcoming device?

Only Apple knows about their future use of UUIDs

Welcome to Ask Different. You tagged this MDM - are you using a specific MDM or writing your own?

Yes, I'm trying to optimize our MDM for scale. I see nanomdm is using the VARCHAR(255) antipattern for UUIDs.

No, not guaranteed. iOS does not use UUIDs.

Although MDM uses UDIDs, they’re deprecated in iOS. A UDID may contain special characters, such as dashes, and its length isn’t guaranteed.

Source: Managing MDM Connections

Good find for the official documentation on this. Thanks for making an answer

Yes, Apple UUIDs conform to the standard in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9562.html (and elsewhere). Sometimes they are called GUID. They are 128 bits long and for all practical purposes, unique.
There is a good explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier There are various formats but the length of 128 bits is constant.

The 128 bit format is binary and not the letters and - the OP has in the question, so you do not store as in the question
